# Is it possible to retrieve Profiles using Salesforce CLI?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've created a custom profile in a scratch org using Salesforce CLI.

The thing is that by using either `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` or `sfdx force:source:pull` commands, only the Admin profile is retrieved.

Is there a way to retrieve the other profiles so that I can deploy them to another org?

Comment: Have you tried  sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Profile" -u <orgAlias> ? it worked me for and retrieved all profile from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've had a chance to do DX work, but I found you can definitely get the profiles by including them in your package.xml or package manifest (Setup > Apps > Package Manager or Setup > Create > Packages). You must explicitly include the profile names in order to get them to appear with the `mdapi` commands.